# ActionCable channel subscription failing when I run the server and query on the Chrome console

Tags: websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am creating a chat app using Rails 5.0.0.beta2 which includes ActionCable for WebSockets. When I start the Puma server and reload the page, I am trying to test and see if I made the connection correctly and whether I can get a subscription confirmation to return in the console. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0WUjGkDFS0&t=7m36s (please see from 7:36 - 8:36) I am seeing neither a meta tag, nor am I able to query for App in the Chrome console.  Does anyone have a suggestion for what I can do to debug this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the `<%= action_cable_meta_tag %>` on your layout (maybe app/views/layouts/application.html.erb )

That's why it's not reconnecting.

I had the same mistake, root layout with the meta tag, going to a page using a different layout, still connect to the websocket, reloading, no meta tag, no websocket.

FYI you can find the code of the video tutorial in your post here : 
http://hectorperezarenas.com/2015/12/26/rails-5-tutorial-how-to-create-a-chat-with-action-cable/

Comment: Thanks, Charly! This answer worked when I put `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` and `<%= action_cable_meta_tag %>` at the top of my layout file.